# How to have validation for calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, column-validation, list-validation

I am working on a calculated column that take value from other two different columns.

The formula is as this:

```
=IF([Detect-Rental/Lease]=1,IF([Detect-Rental/Lease Taxonomy]="Yes",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

As a result the column showing "No" and "Yes" in the list.

But the requirement desire is if it is FALSE it will flag an error. Very much appreciated if anyone can help with this.

Comment: You can add the same formula in list validation settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the same formula in list validation settings to show an error and don't allow users to save the form:

Follow below steps:

1. Go to You SharePoint list.
2. Then go to List settings.
3. Click on **Validation settings**.
4. Add same formula in **Formula** section.
5. Then add suitable error message according to your requirement in **User Message** section.
6. Click **Save**.

**Official Documentation**:

[Edit list settings in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/office/edit-list-settings-in-sharepoint-online-4d35793b-246e-42a3-990c-563a83795b7f?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) - Check Validation settings under General Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Column is used to set value for the current column based on other columns' values of the same list/library, not for validation.

If you want to valid two columns of a list, you can use list Validation settings.

A blog about [the validation setting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/644e54/validation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365/) for your reference.