# Making a Date field required in case the use select In-progress from a choice field using list validation formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, validation, list-validation

I have a SharePoint online custom list which contains 2 columns:

1. **StartDate** of type Date Time
2. **Status** of type Choice field which have values such as Open, In-Progress, Closed.

Now I want to write a list validation formula to make the StartDate required in case the Choice field that is selected = In-Progress? is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using list validation formula. Use formula like below in List settings > Validation settings:

```
=IF([Status] = "In-Progress", NOT(ISBLANK([StartDate])), TRUE)
```

**OR**:

```
=IF([Status] = "In-Progress", IF(ISBLANK([StartDate]), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

Follow steps given here to add formula to list validation settings: [How to have validation for calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280477/how-to-have-validation-for-calculated-column/280480#280480)