# Require column based on another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, administration, calculated-column-formula, column-validation

I am trying to make it that my columns "Event location city" and "Event location country" are required ONLY if Event type is In person or Hybrid. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: what is the column/data type of "Event location city" and "Event location country"?

Comment: Column type for both is "text"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the validation settings of the column from the list settings.

- Go to List Settings
- Click on "Validation Settings" under "General Settings"
- Enter the validation formula as: `=IF([Budget Approved?]=TRUE,IF([Budget Amount]=””,FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)`
- Enter the user (error) message accordingly. I’ve entered “If Budget is approved, you must specify the value of Budget Amount!”.
  [image]
- Click "OK" to save your changes and the result in action:
  [image]

**Reference:** https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/required-field-validation-based-on-other-field-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps for achieving your requirements.

1. Go to list settings, open column settings for "Event location city" & "Event location country" and make sure those are NOT set as required from column settings page.
2. Now, go to list settings page again, select "Validation settings" and use formula like below:

```
=IF(OR([Event Type]="In Person",[Event Type]="Hybrid"),IF(OR(ISBLANK([Event location city]),ISBLANK([Event location country])),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

---

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.
4. Values you are comparing in formula (like "In Person" or "Hybrid") are case-sensitive.

Similar threads and detailed steps to add list validation formula at:

1. [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)
2. [How to have validation for calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280477/how-to-have-validation-for-calculated-column/280480#280480)

Comment: Hi thank you! I did this and it solved the issue...except then it created another one. When I inputted this in the settings, any data in those two columns was then deleted so the columns were blank.

Comment: Strang...Applying list validation formula should not remove any existing list data.

Comment: for some reason, the complete formula does not work but if I split the formula to only look at the city column it works, so thats good enough for me. thanks! the data was disappearing as it turns out I did not have the right permissions.

Comment: You can also try: `=IF(OR([Event Type]="In Person",[Event Type]="Hybrid"),NOT(OR(ISBLANK([Event location city]),ISBLANK([Event location country]))),TRUE)`.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you for city column.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. Thank you!